# How do I transform the result of R2dbcMessageSource into a new Message derived from the query result?

Tags: spring-integration

I am using `R2dbcMessageSource` to query a table for an item and want to use one of the columns to create a message to send to a message handler.

The result of the query is a `Message<Mono<Event>>`, which makes perfect sense.  I want to take `event.getDetails` and create a Message.

Using a `DirectChannel` and `Transformer`, I tried something like this

```
  @Bean
  @Transformer(inputChannel = "fromR2dbcChannel", outputChannel = "fromTransformer")
  public GenericTransformer<Message<Mono<Event>>, Message<String>> monoToString() {
    return message -> {
      Mono<Event> payload = message.getPayload();
      final String details = payload.block();
      if (details == null) {
        return null;
      }
      return MessageBuilder
        .withPayload(details)
        .setHeader("foo", "baz")
        .build();
    };
  }
```

Of course, I would need to put this on its own executor to avoid tying up the thread, but it doesn't work anyway - it throws a class cast exception.

```
error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@1651b34e]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly cannot be cast to org.springframework.messaging.Message, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=Mono.flatMap
```

This seems to be because the `Transformer` is evaluated on assembly.

Using a `FluxMessageChannel` seems strange, since the source is not reactive itself, but it allows me to use a service activator transform the payload.

```
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromR2dbcChannel", reactive = @Reactive("publishMessageWithString"))
    public MessageHandler toValidator() {
      return message -> validationChannel().send(message);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<Flux<Message<Mono<Event>>>, Flux<Message<String>>> publishMessageWithString() {
      return flux -> flux
        .as(toMessageWithString());
    }

    private Function<Flux<Message<Mono<Event>>>, Flux<Message<String>>> toMessageWithString() {
      return messageFlux -> messageFlux.map(message -> {
        final Mono<Event> payload = message.getPayload();
        if (payload != null) {
          final Event event = payload.block();
          if (event != null) {
            return MessageBuilder
              .withPayload(event.getDetails())
              .setHeader("foo", "baz")
              .build();
          }
        }
        return null;
      });
    }
```

In real life, the message handler attached to the service activator does not understand flux natively. It's a `KinesisMessageHandler`.

While this seems to work, it feels awkward.  Is there a better way to transform that's reactor friendly?  Or an adapter that subscribes and invokes a handler?  It seems very reasonable to pass `Message<Mono<Event>>` end to end, so the latter may not be appropriate.   Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Artem, a working test follows:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import io.r2dbc.h2.H2ConnectionConfiguration;
import io.r2dbc.h2.H2ConnectionFactory;
import io.r2dbc.spi.ConnectionFactory;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.config.AbstractR2dbcConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.core.R2dbcEntityTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.dialect.H2Dialect;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.config.EnableR2dbcRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.BridgeTo;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Poller;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.FluxMessageChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.r2dbc.inbound.R2dbcMessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.r2dbc.core.DatabaseClient;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringJUnitConfig;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@Slf4j
@SpringJUnitConfig
@DirtiesContext
public class R2dbcTest {

  @Autowired
  DatabaseClient client;

  R2dbcEntityTemplate entityTemplate;

  @Autowired
  QueueChannel validationChannel;

  @Autowired
  FluxMessageChannel fluxChannel;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() {
    this.entityTemplate = new R2dbcEntityTemplate(this.client, H2Dialect.INSTANCE);

    List<String> statements =
      Arrays.asList(
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS events;",
        "CREATE TABLE events (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, details VARCHAR2 NOT NULL, timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);");

    statements.forEach(it -> this.client.sql(it)
      .fetch()
      .rowsUpdated()
      .as(StepVerifier::create)
      .expectNextCount(1)
      .verifyComplete());
  }

  @Test
  public void validateSuccessfulIntegrationFlow() throws InterruptedException {
    this.entityTemplate.insert(new Event(Instant.now(), "Event details"))
      .then()
      .as(StepVerifier::create)
      .verifyComplete();

    // Validate string
    final Message<?> message = validationChannel.receive();
    assertThat(message.getPayload()).isEqualTo("Event details");
    assertThat(message.getHeaders()).containsKey("foo");
  }

  @Import(R2dbcDatabaseConfiguration.class)
  @Configuration
  @EnableIntegration
  static class SpringIntegrationConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    R2dbcEntityTemplate r2dbcEntityTemplate;

    @Bean
    FluxMessageChannel fromR2dbcChannel() {
      return new FluxMessageChannel();
    }

    @BridgeTo(value = "validationChannel")
    @Bean
    FluxMessageChannel fluxChannel() {
      return new FluxMessageChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    QueueChannel validationChannel() {
      return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromR2dbcChannel", outputChannel = "fluxChannel", async = "true")
    public Mono<Message<String>> transformEvent(Mono<Event> eventMono) {
      return eventMono.map(event ->
        MessageBuilder
          .withPayload(event.getDetails())
          .setHeader("foo", "baz")
          .build());
    }

    // Cron expression is only here because Spring environment is fully initialized before test
    // creates table, so wait for the test to start.
    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "fromR2dbcChannel", poller = @Poller(cron = "30/2 * * * * *"))
    public R2dbcMessageSource r2dbcMessageSourceSelectOne(R2dbcEntityTemplate r2dbcEntityTemplate) {
      R2dbcMessageSource r2dbcMessageSource = new R2dbcMessageSource(r2dbcEntityTemplate,
        "SELECT * FROM events LIMIT 1");
      r2dbcMessageSource.setPayloadType(Event.class);
      r2dbcMessageSource.setExpectSingleResult(true);
      return r2dbcMessageSource;
    }

  }

  @Configuration
  @EnableR2dbcRepositories(basePackages = "org.springframework.integration.r2dbc.repository")
  static class R2dbcDatabaseConfiguration extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
      return createConnectionFactory();
    }

    public ConnectionFactory createConnectionFactory() {
      return new H2ConnectionFactory(H2ConnectionConfiguration.builder()
        .inMemory("r2dbc")
        .username("sa")
        .password("")
        .option("DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1").build());
    }

    @Bean
    public DatabaseClient databaseClient(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
      return DatabaseClient.create(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public R2dbcEntityTemplate r2dbcEntityTemplate(DatabaseClient databaseClient) {
      return new R2dbcEntityTemplate(databaseClient, H2Dialect.INSTANCE);
    }

  }

  @Table("events")
  @Getter
  @Setter
  @RequiredArgsConstructor
  static class Event {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @NonNull
    public Instant timestamp;
    @NonNull
    public String details;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice to re-think your vision about reactive stream and start avoiding calling that `.block()` manually.

Looking to your whole flow requirements, it is really better to make that `fromR2dbcChannel` as a `FluxMessageChannel`, so your `Mono` from R2DBC is going to be subscribed and processed smoothly internally by the framework if there is data.

Your `@Transformer(inputChannel = "fromR2dbcChannel", outputChannel = "fromTransformer")` then could just deal with a plain `Event` as an input parameter. Then your `KinesisMessageHandler` is good to deal with whatever you send to its input channel in the palyoad from that `event.getDetails()`.

**UPDATE**

So, my bad. Independently of the channel for `@InboundChannelAdapter`, it still going to produce a `Mono` in the payload of the message. From here the channel type really doesn't matter. |But at the same time you can make that `validationChannel` as a `FluxMessageChannel` and then your transformer must be changed to the service activator:

```
 @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromR2dbcChannel", outputChannel = "validationChannel", async = "true")
    public Mono<Message<String>> transformEvent(Mono<Event> eventMono) {
      return eventMono.map(
                MessageBuilder
                   .withPayload(event.getDetails())
                   .setHeader("foo", "baz")
                   .build());
    }
```

This way the result `Mono` is going to be subscribed by the `FluxMessageChannel` and the rest of your "blocking" flow should remain the same.

The problem with transformer that it does return the `Message` if result of POJO method is not a `Message`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Although you need to think making it not based on a `GenericTransformer` impl, but like a POJO method: `Message<?> transformEvent(Event event) { return MessageBuilder...}`. Have the same `@Transformer` annotation on this method and remove `Bean`. Fully doesn't look like you need some framework API dependency at this level...

Comment: I was trying to clean up my comment and deleted it.  I responded to Artem's first comment this way:   Thank you for your prompt response.  I think what you mean is that `FluxMessageChannel` understands `Message<Mono<Event>>` and so the transformer would look like `   @Bean
    @Transformer(inputChannel = "fromR2dbcChannel", outputChannel = "validationChannel")
    public GenericTransformer<Event, Message<?>> toNewMessage() {
      return event -> MessageBuilder
        .withPayload(event.getDetails())
        .setHeader("foo", "baz")
        .build();
    }`

Comment: Does it say what channel comes without subscribers?

Comment: Sorry - SO did not refresh and I did not see your response.  I don't mean to make this a chat.  Very much appreciate your looking at this.
`    @Transformer(inputChannel = "fromR2dbcChannel", outputChannel = "validationChannel")
    public Message<String> transformEvent(Event event) {
      return MessageBuilder.withPayload(event.getDetails()).setHeader("foo", "baz").build();
    }`
in @Configuration results in `MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@]; nested exception is SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method transformEvent(reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly) cannot be found`

Comment: Right, you also must make an input channel as a `FluxMessageChannel`

Comment: The input channel is a FluxMessageChannel.  I've updated the test in the original test to show the change to a POJO method invocation for the service activator.

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for your time, the answer, and the great work you are doing on Spring Integration.